# Help getting multiple rows of data from a selected drop down list

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following rows of data in my sheet. Here's 7 as an example, but I essentially have over 1000 rows of data.

|  | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tesla | Jess |
| 2 | Toyota | Kelly |
| 3 | GoPro | Jess |
| 4 | Apple | Linda |
| 5 | Google | Kelly |
| 6 | Netflix | Jess |
| 7 | Oracle | Joe |

What I want to do is have a drop down list or a pick list setup so that when I select Jess from the picklist on cell **F1**, all of Accounts show up like this starting on cell **E4** and below...

|  | Column E | Column F |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pick Rep: | **Jess** |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 | **ACCOUNTS** |  |
| 4 | Tesla |  |
| 5 | GoPro |  |
| 6 | Netflix |  |
| 7 |  |  |
| 8 |  |  |

What Google Sheets formula do I put in cell **E4** (and the rest of the rows in that column downwards) so that every time I change the account owner in cell F1, the appropriate list of accounts show up? If this isn't possible what other options do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=filter(A:A,B:B=$F$1)` in E4 will give you all the accounts belonging to whichever owner you select in F1.

Comment: I just did this but I get the following error ("FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 8373. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.")

Comment: nm! It worked (fat finger on my part). This is brilliant and so easy. Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark the answer as accepted if it meets your requirements.